# Automatically check checkbox when user swipe right in Slidable widget

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, widget, slide

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4C8jX.png)

My Scenario is the Checkbox set checked when user swipe right. Tried Slidable widget but it's require full screen slide to detect an event. I've attached an image for reference. Help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Dismissible widget (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iEMgjrfuc58&ab_channel=Flutter) and onDissmissed callback you can put a setstate changing the boolean for the checkbox

In addition you can set the background to anything you want

Comment: this widget needs complete slide to detect event. I need slight slide to get event.